# How to handle an image file from googleusercontent CDN in Node?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, node-request, google-cdn

Trying to request an image from Google CDN and upload it to S3.
Using the `https://github.com/request/request` library and `Node / Express`;

A little confused how to handle payload coming back from Google CDN. 
[image]

The image comes back in the body field and in encoded. Not sure how it is encoded.

Given a URL to a Google CDN:

`const fileURL = https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/EWE1234rFL006WfQKuAVrsYMOiKnM6iztPtLgXM5U…3i26LoPHQwPTQME7ne3XoMriKVjUo3hrhwWw1211223`

```
  request(fileURL, (err, res, body) => {

     //NOT sure how to handle the response here??
     //Trying base64
     fs.writeFileSync(`.tmp/file1.png`, body, {encoding: 'base64'});

     //Trying Binary
     fs.writeFileSync(`.tmp/file.png`, body, {encoding: 'binary'});
  }
```

body comes back as:

`�PNG↵↵IHDRv&vл� IDATx�}���<z�f���];��o]��A�N�.po�/�/R���..............`

1). Request an image from `googleusercontent` Google CDN (image was originally pasted in a Google Doc)

2). Create an image file and write to disk on the Server.

Neither of the `fs.writeFileSync` seem to produce a readable image file.

Any advice on handling this would be awesome..

Comment: What are you using to upload to S3? You can most probably pass the body as it is.

Comment: Sorry, I should emphasize that the issue is that the image being written is not readable. Going to edit my post. Trying to understand how to handle the string returned from Google and create a file from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the response as the body to your S3 upload.

```
var request = require('request'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    aws = require('aws-sdk'),
    s3 = new aws.S3(),
    url = 'https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-2XOcvsAH-kc/VHvmCm1aOoI/AAAAAAABtzg/SDdN1Vg5FFs/s346/14%2B-%2B1';

# Store in a file
request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.gif'));

request(url, {encoding: 'binary'}, function(error, response, body) {
    # Another way to store in a file
    fs.writeFile('file.gif', body, 'binary', function(err) {});

    # Upload to S3
    s3.upload({
        Body: body,
        Bucket: 'BucketName',
        Key: 'file.gif',
    }, function(err, data) {});
});
```

Comment: Yes this is basically what I am doing. The file that is written to disk is unreadable.

Comment: Note the encoding part on the request call `request(url, {encoding: 'binary'}`